# How to fix Discord API: Unknown Message error?

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm trying to make a meme command but whenever I try to use it I get this error "DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message".

This was working earlier but when I came back to my PC it started glitching out.

Here's my code

```
const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");
const randomPuppy = require("random-puppy");
const usedCommandRecently = new Set();

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    aliases: ["memes", "reddit"],
    category: "fun",
    description: "Sends a random meme",
    run: async (client, message, args) => {
        if (message.deletable) message.delete();
        var Channel = message.channel.name
        //Check it's in the right channel
        if(Channel != "memes") {
            const channelembed = new RichEmbed()
                .setColor("BLUE")
                .setTitle(`Use me in #memes`)
                .setDescription(`Sorry ${message.author.username} this command is only usable in #memes !`)
            return message.channel.send(channelembed);
        }
        //Check cooldown
        if(usedCommandRecently.has(message.author.id)){
            const cooldownembed = new RichEmbed()
                .setColor("GREEN")
                .setTitle("Slow it down, pal")
                .setDescription(`Sorry ${message.author.username} this command has a 30 second cooldown per member, sorry for any inconvenice this may cause`)
            message.channel.send(cooldownembed)
        } else{
            //Post meme
            const subReddits = ["dankmeme", "meme", "me_irl"];
            const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

            const img = await randomPuppy(random);
            const embed = new RichEmbed()
                .setColor("RANDOM")
                .setImage(img)
                .setTitle(`From /r/${random}`)
                .setURL(`https://reddit.com/r/${random}`);

            message.channel.send(embed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log()`'s to your code? Like log a process of steps and figure out what message block is causing the problem? It looks alright to me.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but maybe problem in your require block.
`const { RichEmbed } = require("discord.js");`

the right way its:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let cooldownembed  = new Discord.RichEmbed();
```

and why you use **return** here

```
return message.channel.send(channelembed);
```

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. Also, I used return so it didn't do the rest of the code (sending the meme) so they did it in the right channel